# String array calculation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, arrays

i have a string array like

```
String[] resultYears = {"2013/07", "2013/08", "2013/09", "2013/10", "2013/11", "2013/12", "2014/01"};
```

when i get this through response in my jsp,

```
<% String[] resultYears = (String[]) request.getAttribute("resultYears");%>
```

i am getting the remainders of their respective values. How can i get same as above string value?

Comment: I'm confused - what are you trying to do? You want to output the remainders as a String array?

Comment: i getting remainders, i want to get same as above string array values. :(

Comment: Have you tried `String[] resultYears = {new String("2013/07"),......}` ??

Comment: @Vishal K same problem. no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in your JAVA Class

```
String[] resultYears = {"'2013/07'", "'2013/08'", "'2013/09'", "'2013/10'", "'2013/11'", "'2013/12'", "'2014/01'"};
request.setAttribute("resultYears", resultYears);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the strings using single quotes like this

```
"'2013/08'"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instantiating a Date object with the YYYY/MM desired and do a .getTime() on it, then pass that through the request in String value.  On the far end, translate it back into a pretty, human readable format.